# Using Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to use Google Cloud Vision API, but facing some issues. Let me explain the steps I took and then the issue I'm facing. I'm running this code in Windows 10.

1. Download and install "GoogleCloudSDKInstaller".
2. gcloud auth application-default login to activate my login
   credential
3. Used [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/vision/cloud-client/face_detection/faces.py) code to run the face detector, for the image
   in my local system.
4. cd into the folder where image exists
5. Then run the following code:

   python detect_face.py "image.jpg"

But I'm getting this error:

> raise EnvironmentError('Project was not passed and could not be '
>   OSError: Project was not passed and could not be determined from the
>   environment.

Can anyone please tell me why I'm getting this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the Google Vision API but in C# with Visual Studios 2017, and I needed to set the environment variable to GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CREDENTIALS. 
You might have this problem, try to look on the net how to set it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I fixed this problem following this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMY0qDg16y4&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfGVb3yucqvKtUgwOJgZWCm&index=2

Comment: So it was the same thing ? 
Happy to have helped you !